# share image to particular facebook fan page in android

Tags: android, facebook

I want share image to particular facebook fan page.I have successfully uploaded image from camera to default facebook album.Please help how can i do this.

Comment: `share image to particular facebook page.` Do you mean you want to share on friends wall or on your wall ?

Comment: to a fan particular facebook fan page

Comment: Then you will have to get all your facebook's friends list and then you can share on particular fan's page.

Comment: Why i require facebook's friend list for that

Comment: Then how will you share image on your friends wall without getting friends?

Comment: i don't want to share that image on friend's wall. Suppose i liked some page & want to share my image on that page. How can i do this

Comment: on which page you want to share image? AFAIK Facebook api does not allow you to post anything on anyone's wall except your friends and your wall.

Comment: i don't want share the image on my friend's wall.I want to share on the facebook fan page that i liked like any celebrity fan page etc.